# What causes the error when using ggplot plot on different OSes?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm getting a strange error when loading `.Rdata` produced on one OS and transferred to another. On a Windows machine I generate a large number of plots and store them in a `.Rdata` file. I then transfer them to a linux server running CentOS 5 and access them by loading the file and recalling the plot.

When I run the following lines on CentOS I get an error:

```
library(ggplot2)
load('mydata.Rdata')
p


Error in UseMethod("facet_train_layout") : 
  no applicable method for 'facet_train_layout' applied to an object of class "c('proto', 'environment')"
```

The Windows 7 OS that was used to produce this .Rdata file is using the following version of R:

> R version 2.14.2 (2012-02-29) Copyright (C) 2012 The R Foundation for
>   Statistical Computing ISBN 3-900051-07-0 Platform:
>   x86_64-pc-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

The CentOS system that produces an error is as follows:

> R version 2.14.2 (2012-02-29) Copyright (C) 2012 The R Foundation for
>   Statistical Computing ISBN 3-900051-07-0 Platform: i686-pc-linux-gnu
>   (32-bit)

The `ggplot2` version on both systems is `ggplot2_0.9.2.1`. This process has worked fine for the last six months, the only problem has been today due to an update and I don't understand what is going wrong.

Both versions of R were upgraded to 2.14.2, as well as the ggplot package to ggplot2_0.9.2.1.

Comment: What specifically did you update just before it stopped working?

Comment: Can you be more specific, please? Which box, and from what to what. (I'm assuming there's a reason you're so far behind on R versions and upgrading all the way isn't an option...?)

Comment: Sorry, I'll update my question with more info, but both were upgraded today.

Comment: Not that it matters anymore, but your edit did not add any new information.  We already knew you now have R 2.14.2 with ggplot2_0.9.2.1

Comment: I was clarifying that I updated them both today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume the old version was 0.8.9 or below. There was a fundamental change with version 0.9.0:

> FACETS
>
> - Converted from proto to S3 objects, and class methods (somewhat) documented   in `facet.r`. This should make it easier to develop new
>     types of facetting   specifications.

See http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/NEWS for more information